# Generate fixed length random id by year as character

Tags: r

I would like to create random id with fixed `length 8`

Here is sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4), year=c(2001,2001,2001,2010,2010,2002,2002,2002,2002,2005,2005),x=seq(0,0.1,0.01))
```

My attempt:

```
x$new.id <- ave(x$id, x$year, FUN = function(x) rnorm(x,90000000,100000))
```

The random generated new.id should have equal `id's` for given `id` and `year`

There must be simple solution, yet I cannot find one. Thanks.

EDIT: Or otherwise how to create new `8 digit id` for given number of rows.

Desired output: `the column new.id should be class character`

```
   new.id year  new.id
   1   1 2001 89957391
   2   1 2001 89957391
   3   1 2001 89957391
   4   2 2010 90331214
   5   2 2010 90331214
   6   3 2002 89995435
   7   3 2002 89995435
   8   3 2002 89995435
   9   3 2002 89995435
   10  4 2005 90058279
   11  4 2005 90058279
```

Comment: Maybe `transform(x,  new.id = ave(id, year, FUN = function(x) rnorm(1, 9e7, 1e5)))`?

Comment: @David. I deleted this question, but I thought myself, it could be kind of okay to leave it here on SO, what do you think? It is not particularly useful, but who knows :)

Comment: I don't know, you are the owner of your question and you can decide what ever you want to do with it. Who knows, maybe someone will come up with a better solution that can be useful for others.

Comment: So if you would submit your above solution, but please also with converting the new.id as `character`. For some reason I'm getting long number with a dot in between. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, it gives me correct result for the provided data set

Comment: I would like to turn the column `new.id` into class `character`. If I do: `transform(x, new.id = as.character(ave(id, year, FUN = function(x) rnorm(1, 9e7, 1e5))))` I get the long number with dot in between.

Comment: The data goes into database and the database is set so that the column is as character otherwise I get errors.

Comment: Try `transform(x, new.id = ave(id, year, FUN = function(x) as.character(round(rnorm(1, 9e7, 1e5)))))`. You should decide how to round your values, either use `round`, `floor` or `ceiling`.

Comment: Yes this is it! If you would submit it and ready to accept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, `rnorm` isn't returning `integer` by default and seems to be rounded  while printed, is there a reason that are not just using `sample`?

Comment: Yes, if you would submit with sample that's totally fine. Just need to be kind of random and the rest as explained above.

Comment: See my edit, it seems like there could be some fundamental error with the original solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with your *coding* approach (to use `ave` in that manner), though if you want to generate only one value per each group, you should pass `1` into `rnorm`s `n` parameter.

The biggest problem as I see it here, is that you want to generate a random number of class `integer` (and then convert to `character` class) while `rnorm` returns `double` by definition.

So you could potentially do this (using `round` or `floor` or `ceiling`)

```
transform(x, new.id = ave(id, 
                          year, 
                          FUN = function(x) as.character(round(rnorm(1, 9e7, 1e5)))))
```

But it seems to me that more appropriate way would be to use `sample` instead

```
indx <- 1e7:(1e8 - 1)
transform(x, new.id = ave(id, year, FUN = function(x) as.character(sample(indx, 1))))
```

---

**Edit**: Now that I came to think about it a little more, it is possible that for a large enough data set you will have duplicated `new.id`s because you are independantly calling `sample` function each time. It seem to me that the best solution would be first creating a data set with new indexes per each `id` while generated by a single `sample` call and then merge it back to the data set. This Operation could be best done using the `data.table` package (because of it efficient joins and the ability to only add a single column while joining), something like the following should work

```
library(data.table)
y <- data.table(id = unique(x$id), 
                new.id = as.character(sample(indx, length(unique(x$id)))))
setkey(setDT(x), id) ; setkey(y, id)
x[y, new.id := i.new.id]
```

This will update you original data set by reference (without the need in `<-` assignment). You can convert back to `data.frame` (if you wish) by simply doing `setDF(x)`.